# What is the standard way to organize Qt code?

Tags: qt, coding-style

I want to know what is the standard way to organize Qt code using Qt Creator? I have this question because I am a Qt beginner & learn Qt following a c++ based tutorial i.e. Qt addressbook tutorial. Code is split very nice in that tutorial in header files & cpp files. But when I tried to build same app using Qt Creator, its quite different. I mean like there is even no declaration of controls nether in header file nor cpp file. They just dump everything to a ui file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I do:

Generate the code from Qt Creator. This gives you a class with some name like Ui::MyDialog. Then, create a class that derives from Ui::MyDialog. Create the slots you need for the dialog in the derived class.

In the constructor, call the setupUi() method, and then connect the slots to the signals in the dialog's widgets. Elsewhere in your program (in the main() function, maybe) construct the derived class and then call its show() method.

I notice that Qt Creator doesn't show you the code it generates from your dialog's UI file. It might be instructive to use Qt Designer to see the C++ code it produces. This might give you a better idea of what to do with Creator.

A good book for learning Qt is C++ GUI Programming with Qt 4 by Blanchette and Summerfield: [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0132354160/ref=ase_trolltech/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132354160). If you're interested in Qt, I *highly* recommend this.

Comment: "Then, create a class that derives from Ui::MyDialog". That's so Qt3 :) Better make the Ui::MyDialog a private member.

Answer (score 0):

Although GUI IDE environments seem to encourage you to mix GUI code with program logic, you do not need to do this. You can use the GUI designer to lay out your GUI and in the wrapper class, connect the signals and slots of your widgets as needed for GUI logic and emit custom signals so that program logic in another class can act on it without mixing the two.